# How to "one-click" delete a file that is currently playing on Media Player Classic

Tags: video, windows-7, media-player, media

Is there a way to do it straight from MPC or could I create a separate program that would detect the file that is currently playing and delete it (I know it is possible to delete files while they are currently playing in MPC).

I have no experience in programming windows but I do have a lot of experience in scientific programming, so feel free to elaborate...

Comment: Superuser is another Stack Exchange site.  If there's a way to do it that doesn't involve programming, that would be the place to ask about it.  Stack Overflow is for getting answers that are going to involve programming.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething Sounds good, I am fine with the programming route. I just need some direction on what language to use and what specific subroutines may be helpful. Thanks for the tip on superuser, xposted it there too...

Comment: If you want to solve this with programming, you will first need to get your hands on the MPC object model to see what information they make available to other applications.

Comment: Ok, I got you wrong, I was thinking you were talking about Microsoft's Media Player. But since MPC is an open source product under GPL, it may be easy to contact the developers and just ask them - did you try that?

Comment: @DocBrown I haven't tried that, I will give it a go, thanks for the idea.